# Preprocessing Categorical attributes in machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
numpy.unique()  vs Pandas.get_dummies()
```

numpy.unique() coverts the data into an array of all the K categories and returns the index of each values as the new column, whereas get_dummies() just creates k columns each having (0,1) values.

**Which method for Converting categorical data into numbers is best for machine learning and Why ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For preprocessing categorical attributes, it depends majorly on the fact that does the categorical attributes have an ordered relation or not.

For example, an attribute like Temperature which is comprised of four levels: Very High, High, Medium, Low. These are termed as ordinal variables and in this case, the conversion to numerical indexes is justified. So Very High becomes "1", High becomes "2" and so on.

But if the variable is a nominal variable, which has no ordering information, the numerical indexes would most probably result in poor results because of misinformation that is provided to the model.
For example for the attribute like gender, it doesn't make sense to convert those to numerical indexes as, "1" for male and "2" for female as this gives a biased information to the model making female rank higher than male value when in most cases they are both equal and have no order between them. Thus it makes better sense to make create k columns with binary values for each variable.

Comment: but how does "1" for male and "2" for female gives a biased information to the model, as far as both testing and training data have the same values, how would it affect the result in the end ?

Comment: It would steer the model to think that the values have an ordinal relationship between them. Meaning model would see the female as higher in ranking as compared to male but that's not the information you want to pass to the model.

Comment: Machine learning isn't magic and it only works when a problem which needs to be solved, is represented as accurately as it can be from the real world.

Comment: ok thats helps but wont having an increase in attribute columns make the results vary.

Comment: How do you imply that? Can you elaborate a little ?

Comment: The number of columns isn't really important until and unless you are taking into the account the computational efficiency. If we are just talking about model efficiency it won't have any negative impact if increasing the number of columns results in a better representation of the problem statement. After all, the transformations applied to the training data will also be applied to the testing dataset as well. So I am still not sure what you are trying to imply by variations in results.

Comment: I mean an attribute like temperature after get_dummies results in 4 attributes (temperature_high,temperature_low) each having (0,1) values, that is an increase in number of attributes than before, but as u said above it makes it more clear. Also is any other processing suppose to be applied/done on the resulting four attributes or can they be fed to the algorithm as it is.

Comment: But for temperature, the temperature being an ordinal variable, in this case, you can convert it into numerical indexes so that would give you the temperature column containing 4 numerical values from 0 to 3 (or 1 to 4) however you like.

The binary one hot encoding applies more to the case of gender, but even in that once the multiple columns are generated we can directly feed it into the algorithm. Just make sure you make the same transformations to the testing dataset and any future input as well.

Comment: NOTE: Also in this gender case we only need to create one column which can either contain 0 for male and 1 for female or vice versa, because this one column will contain the entire information about the gender column which the model needs to know.

More than one columns are created for a nominal variable when the number of categories is more than 2 for that nominal variable.

Comment: No problem @RitvikKhanna